# Selecting rows from a table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a table given by

```
example1=Table[N[x^(x/r), 5],{r, 1, 11},{x, 1, 10}];
example2=Accumulate[example1];
example2
```

I would like to use `example2` to create a new table that uses `example2`'s data, but only shows every `n`th row of the `example2` table - in this case (for example), every `2`nd, `3`rd or `4`th row.

How do I do this?

Comment: Don't assign something in `TableForm` to a variable. `TableForm` is meant for display only, and it cannot be used for computing (without removing it first). Thus, use `example2 = Accumulate[...];`, then use `example2 // TableForm` for display or `example2[[;; ;; 3]]` to take every third row. Look up these in the docs: `Part`, `Span`, `TableForm`.

Comment: OK, so let's lose the `TableForm`. Point taken. Question now edited. But I'm new enough to all this that, whilst I can see that in principle `Span` and `Part` could give me what I want, I'm not entirely sure how to put it into practice...

Comment: But I showed you the exact code you need in my first comment—`[[` is `Part` and `;;` is `Span`.  Here it is again: `example2[[;; ;; 3]]` to take every third row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
example2[[;;;;2]]
```

> {{1.0000, 4.0000, 27.000, 256.00, 3125.0, 46656., 8.2354*10^5, 
>     1.6777*10^7, 3.8742*10^8, 1.0000*10^10},
>    {3.0000, 7.5874, 35.196, 
>     278.35, 3195.5, 46908., 8.2454*10^5, 1.6782*10^7, 3.8744*10^8, 
>     1.0000*10^10},
>    {5.0000, 10.321, 39.409, 285.38, 3208.0, 46931., 
>     8.2459*10^5, 1.6782*10^7, 3.8744*10^8, 1.0000*10^10},
>    {7.0000, 
>     12.800, 42.742, 290.11, 3215.0, 46942., 8.2461*10^5, 1.6782*10^7, 
>     3.8744*10^8, 1.0000*10^10},
>   {9.0000, 15.156, 45.694, 293.96, 3220.2,
>      46949., 8.2462*10^5, 1.6782*10^7, 3.8744*10^8, 1.0000*10^10}}

Alternatively, you can [`Drop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Drop.html) every other row starting with the second row:

```
Drop[example2, {2, -1, 2}]
```

> same result

Comment: OK, got it now! Much appreciated :-)

Comment: @Richard, my pleasure.